# Instruct to typescript that a class assigns properties dinamically

Tags: typescript

I have a simple class definition like below:

```
class Model {
  constructor(props?:{}) {
    _extend(props, this);
  }
}
```

Where the constructor accepts an object as argument and copies its properties to the instance with an `_extend` function defined somewhere.

My problem is that Typescript complains about properties that are not defined in the class definition when I try to access to then.

```
let model = new Model({id: 1, name: 'coyote'});
model.id;  // Property 'id' does not exist on type Model
```

Is there a way to tell to **TypeScript** that this class in specific can have properties not defined in the class?

Currently I am accessing to the properties using the form **`instance['prop_name']`** in my test files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider an alternative using factory method:

```
class Model {
    private constructor(props?: any) { }

    static create<T>(props?: T): T & Model {
        return new Model(props) as T & Model;
    }
}

let model = Model.create({ a: 123 });
```

If you are fine with a bad looking class definition, you may try this:

```
class ModelClass {
    constructor(props?: any) { }
}

type ModelStatic = {
    new <T>(props?: T): ModelClass & T;
} & typeof ModelClass;

const Model: ModelStatic = ModelClass;
type Model = ModelClass;

let model = new Model({ foo: 123 });
```

But I would suggest the first approach anyway.

Comment: I didn't know TypeScript was able to infer `T` from a parameter. Wow. Very impressive!

Comment: It would be nice to do this directly from the constructor. Or a special syntax in an `interface` that declares that a class that implements it can have any number of properties.

Comment: Actually you can achieve the results if you would accept a bad looking class definition. Will update the answer in minutes.

Comment: I will give a try to the second approach to see how it behaves. Actually have a class factory function that returns a new defined class (`Model`). So, having a bad looking definition is not a bad approach I thinks. Of course, As long as the compiled Javascript code has the same behavior and doesn't have any side effect.

Comment: Then that would be fine. Actually you don't even need the `type Model =` thing if you are creating the class constructor with a method (you lose it anyway). Just `return Model as { new <T>(props?: T): Model & T; } & typeof Model;` should do.